# Suppress observing a CDI event with a specific qualifier

Tags: java, events, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a CDI event (say eventA that doesn't have any qualifiers) that gets fired, eventA has several consumers. In a special case, I need to fire eventA with a specific qualifier (say qualifierX).
Now, all the consumers of eventA will essentially receive eventA (with and without qualifierX).

I would like to maintain the behavior my consumers to only observe eventA without qualifierX.

P.S. I am not allowed to modify every consumer.

I thought about extending eventA with a child eventB and having this eventB fired, but this will also trigger eventA observers.

Is there a direct way to do this in CDI?

Comment: If you would like your consumers to only observe `EventA` without qualifier, than you should have defined them as `@Observes @Default EventA`. From what you say, they are now bound to `@Any` event - hence they will receive the event as long as the payload type fits. **About extending** - that wont work, `EventB` will still have type of `EventA`, therefore it will notify the original observers. **However, if you could change the `EventA` class**, you might create a superclass (`MyEvent`) and have `EventA extends MyEvent`. Then firing an event with `MyEvent` will *not* notify original observers.

Comment: You could also write a CDI extension that looks for `ProcessObserverMethod` and modifies the qualifiers.

Comment: @Siliarus I think I will go with this solution. Thank you

Comment: @JohnAment I am sorry I didn't mention that I am using CDI 1.0 which doesn't really allow me to modify the qualifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like your consumers to only observe `EventA` without qualifier, than you *should have* defined them as `@Observes @Default EventA`. From what you say, they are now bound to `@Any` event - hence **they will receive the event as long as the payload type fits**.

About extending - that wont work, `EventB` will still have type of `EventA`, therefore it will notify the original observers. However, if you could change the `EventA` class, **you might create a superclass** (`MyEvent`) and have `EventA extends MyEvent`. Then firing an event with `MyEvent` *will not notify original observers*.